# how to show TreeView in DropDown

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build an application in cakephp 1.3. i have a treeview menu in my view. I have used jquery dynatree for this. This tree works using ajax. I send my data from controller to view in json format.

Now my requirement is that I want to show this treeview in a dropdown. If any body can refer me any jquery api, or anyother good solution.

to be more clear please visit this link 
[jQuery TreeView Menu (v1.4)](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/index.htm.)

I want demo three in my dropdown menu.

Waiting for your expert suggestion.

thanks

Answer (score 7):

This will be helpful [Basic ComboTree](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [mcDropdown jQuery Plug-in v1.3.2](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm)